# Table with an array, return hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array `["1","1","a","b","y"]` and `table1`:

```
table1

POSITION    NAME     VALUE     CODE
1           Animal   Dog       1
1           Animal   Cat       2
1           Animal   Bird      3
2           Place    USA       1
2           Place    Other     2
3           Color    Red       a
3           Color    Blue      b
3           Color    Orange    c
4           Age      Young     a
4           Age      Middle    b
4           Age      Old       c
5           Alive    Yes       y
5           Alive    No        n
```

For each element in the array, I would like to find a matching `POSITION`-`CODE` combination in `table1`, where `POSITION` is the index of the element (base 1) and `CODE` is the element in the array. Then, I want to return a hash that contains  the corresponding `NAME` and `VALUE` for the matches as a key and its value. The output would be:

```
{"Animal" => "Dog", "Place" => "USA", "Color" => "Red", "Age" => "Middle", "Alive" => "Yes"}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: What is your DB client.. Please always mention it..

Comment: Why does `"b"` map to "Age" => "Middle" rather than "Color" => "Blue"?

Comment: Since the b is the 4th character in the array, it will match with the items labeled as position 4.  I know arrays include a zero index, but this is what the table I was given looks like.

Comment: @sabrams That's a crucial thing for you.. Please mention it in your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to map several `codes` arrays against the same table. Suppose you first read the table into an array:

```
a = [["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"],
     ["1", "Animal", "Cat", "2"],
     ["1", "Animal", "Bird", "3"],
     ["2", "Place", "USA", "1"],
     ["2", "Place", "Other", "2"],
     ["3", "Color", "Red", "a"],
     ["3", "Color", "Blue", "b"],
     ["3", "Color", "Orange", "c"],
     ["4", "Age", "Young", "a"],
     ["4", "Age", "Middle", "b"],
     ["4", "Age", "Old", "c"],
     ["5", "Alive", "Yes", "y"],
     ["5", "Alive", "No", "n"]]
```

and

```
codes = ["1","1","a","b","y"]
```

Then you could do this:

```
codes.zip(a.chunk { |a| a.first }).map { |l,(_,b)|
  b.find { |c| c.last == l}[1...-1] }.to_h
  #=> {"Animal"=>"Dog", "Place"=>"USA", "Color"=>"Red",
  #    "Age"=>"Middle", "Alive"=>"Yes"}
```

The steps:

```
enum0 = a.chunk { |a| a.first }
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #   #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f8d6a0269b8>:each>
```

To see the contents of the enumerator,

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [["1", [["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"], ["1", "Animal", "Cat", "2"],
  #           ["1", "Animal", "Bird", "3"]]],
  #    ["2", [["2", "Place", "USA", "1"], ["2", "Place", "Other", "2"]]],
  #    ["3", [["3", "Color", "Red", "a"], ["3", "Color", "Blue", "b"],
              ["3", "Color", "Orange", "c"]]],
  #    ["4", [["4", "Age", "Young", "a"], ["4", "Age", "Middle", "b"], 
  #           ["4", "Age", "Old", "c"]]],
  #    ["5", [["5", "Alive", "Yes", "y"], ["5", "Alive", "No", "n"]]]] 

p = codes.zip(enum0)
  #=> [["1", ["1", [["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"],
  #                 ["1", "Animal", "Cat", "2"],
  #                 ["1", "Animal", "Bird", "3"]]]],
  #    ["1", ["2", [["2", "Place", "USA", "1"],
  #                 ["2", "Place", "Other", "2"]]]],
  #    ["a", ["3", [["3", "Color", "Red", "a"],
  #                 ["3", "Color", "Blue", "b"],
  #                 ["3", "Color", "Orange", "c"]]]],
  #    ["b", ["4", [["4", "Age", "Young", "a"],
  #                 ["4", "Age", "Middle", "b"],
  #                 ["4", "Age", "Old", "c"]]]],
  #    ["y", ["5", [["5", "Alive", "Yes", "y"],
  #                 ["5", "Alive", "No", "n"]]]]] 

l,(_,b) = enum1.next
l #=> "1" 
b #=> [["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"], ["1", "Animal", "Cat", "2"],
  #    ["1", "Animal", "Bird", "3"]] 
enum1 = b.find
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"],
  #                  ["1", "Animal", "Cat", "2"],
  #                  ["1", "Animal", "Bird", "3"]]:find> 
c = enum1.next
  #=> ["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"] 
c.last == l
  #=> true
```

so `enum1` returns

```
d = ["1", "Animal", "Dog", "1"]
e = d[1...-1]
  #=> ["Animal", "Dog"]
```

So the first element of `x.zip(y)` is mapped to `["Animal", "Dog"]`.

After performing the same operations for each of the other elements of `enum1`, `x.zip(y)` equals:

```
f = [["Animal", "Dog"], ["Place", "USA"], ["Color","Red"],
     ["Age",  "Middle"], ["Alive", "Yes"]]
```

The final steps is

```
f.to_h
  #=> {"Animal"=>"Dog", "Place"=>"USA", "Color"=>"Red",
  #    "Age"=>"Middle", "Alive"=>"Yes"}
```

or for < v2.0

```
Hash[f]
```

Comment: Would this still perform well if the table had closer to 200 records and the array had closer to 25 elements?

Comment: @sabrams You have those _data_ inside a _table_ right ?

Comment: Yes, the data in table1 is in it's own table/model.  The array will be an input from earlier code.

Comment: If you had only a single record to match agains the table, a query might be more efficient. (I don't really know--not my field.)  This is mainly for the case where you want to match several arrays against the same table.

Comment: @sabrams What's your Ruby version ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland how do you read a table into an array with the format you have given?